# Minikube doesn't work on Mac with hyperkit driver and VPN

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vpn, minikube, hyperkit

I tried to run minikube with hyperkit driver on VPN.
While installing with `minikube start --vm=true`
This error occurred.

`❗  This VM is having trouble accessing https://k8s.gcr.io`

Someone said from github community, I should use docker but I can not use docker driver for now, because I should install ingress addon, when I tried with docker, it said this addon doesn't work with docker, so it recommends to use the alternative.

Is there any solution to make hyperkit work on VPN?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6296). You can try using `--vmdriver=virtualbox` or `--vmdriver=vmwarefusion`. Note that you will either have to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [VMware Fusion](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads/details?downloadGroup=FUS-1200&productId=1040&rPId=52084) (Paid license required)

Comment: Thank you , I tried with virtualbox but there is another issue.

`❌  Problems detected in kubelet:
    Oct 06 22:23:34 minikube kubelet[4062]: E1006 22:23:34.576534    4062 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod ff7d12f9e4f14e202a85a7c5534a3129 ("kube-scheduler-minikube_kube-system(ff7d12f9e4f14e202a85a7c5534a3129)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-scheduler" with RunContainerError: "failed to start container \"510ed6954ca7360ad9d9525ad37fcaf12bc47bed21e31bc65b7a1bf10038f7d1\": Error response from daemon: cannot join network of a non running container:`

Comment: Can you uninstall your VPN to discard that the VPN is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac and I faced the same issue. I solved it by applying the flag `--hyperkit-vpnkit-sock=auto` to `minikube start --vm=true`. This will, according to the [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/):

> Location of the VPNKit socket used for networking. If empty, disables Hyperkit VPNKitSock, if 'auto' uses Docker for Mac VPNKit connection, otherwise uses the specified VSock (hyperkit driver only)